# SharePoint list view security with export to excel

Tags: sharepoint-2013, excel-2013, powerquery, powerbi

By using views in SharePoint you can effectively restrict who has access to data. For example, on a lookup, by specifying to filter only when not empty you can restrict access to data where the permissions are restricted on the data in in related list. Or, for example, on the created field being set to [me].  You can then set the permissions on the views to only allow specific people access to each view.

However, what happens in regards to access to this data when accessing it from excel? If connecting to SharePoint data directly from excel, will you only be able to access the data via the views created, or can all users access the list data directly? Can you restrict who has access to the list data in excel?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint View only do the view change it does not actually manage any permission in row or column level. so if the user connect the list with excel and they have read permission on the list then they can see all the data